# Encrypt ID in routers URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have controllers like

Records, Items .... where I used ID 
/records/1, /records/2 .... /items/1, /items/2 .... 
Prompt the best variant at which it is possible to receive the cipher type of type / records / H $ Ur95% 92 (any hash) for all controllers (Records, Items ...). The first option was to create a table with the set id <-> hash and check the transmitted hash in the router. But I think this option is not quite right, because when adding a new record (ID), you need to record (check) the new hash. I think there is a simple option to do all this nicely through routers, without any additional tables.
Like this

```
$id= Crypt::encrypt(['id' => 1 ]);
<a href="{{url('/records/',$id)}}" target="_blank">get record</a>
```

And then check in router like

```
Route::get('/{id}', function($id){
 ..... Crypt::decrypt($id);............
});
```

Maybe find any other ways where we have global rules for all controllers to encrypt and decrypt IDs only in router area (without any guid/uuid).

Comment: What about to using UUID? Did you try https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid? :)

Comment: Also, in using this package you'll not need to record new hash, it's auto-generated when persisting model instance.

Comment: If you want create hashId like youtube, you can try `HashIds` https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids (http://hashids.org/php/)

Comment: An option would be to use md5 and store the hash in the DB or key value store like redis but this depends on how far you wish to go with encrypting or hasing as hashing is different to encrypting, When you say hash, it mostly means one way thus the only real way to reverse the hash is brute force however knowing the original value would make this easier, I use both the hashids package @haidang has referfed to and the md5 method i have refereed to, I store the md5 value of the id when i create the entity for example in my DB i have the following:  ID | MD5_ID | NAME | ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @haidang mentioned, you can use Vinkla's Hashids(https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids) package.

## Steps for Implementation

### Installation

```
composer require vinkla/hashids
```

If you are running laravel 5.5+, then the package will be auto discovered. Else add the service provider to **config/app.php** file

### Service Provider (For Laravel 5.4 and lesser)

Add the service provider to config/app.php in the providers array, or if you're using Laravel 5.5, this can be done via the automatic package discovery.

```
Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider::class
```

If you want you can use the facade. Add the reference in config/app.php to your aliases array.

```
'Hashids' => Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::class
```

and then

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

### Usage

```
// You can alias this in config/app.php.
use Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids;

Hashids::encode(4815162342);

Hashids::decode('doyouthinkthatsairyourebreathingnow');
// This example is simple and there are far more methods available.
```

Comment: Hi @Saravanan Sampathkumar, first thx for answer. I try install it but get next mess https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids/issues/71 what I need to do yet to install this package?

Comment: You seem like installing wrong version of vinkla's package. You should do 2.2.0 version. Try doing "composer require vinkla/hashids 2.2.0"